# Segmentation fault (core dumped) C++ as I use a lot of memory

Tags: c++, memory, segmentation-fault, coredump

In C++ I am using my 'user' class, and my code has only the following 3 lines:

```
    cout<<"size of user = "<<sizeof(user)<<endl;    //prints 160
    cout<<"size of all users = "<<NUM_OF_USERS*sizeof(user)<<endl;  

    user users[NUM_OF_USERS];  //creates an array of users of size NUM_OF_USERS.
```

When the NUM_OF_USERS is only 10,000 it works fine (and even all my program works fine). But when I increase it to 1000,000 it gives the error below (for only these 3 lines of code).

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So, there is no other problems (no pointers or anything). The problem is there is no memory for this big number of objects of this class (needs 16,000,000 Bytes = 16MB).

I am using a UNIX machine which has a pretty big memory, so I think 16 MB is not a lot. So, How can I increase the memory given to this specific process?

Comment: You are creating the array on the stack which is limited in space to a few MB or less. Try using `std::vector<user> users(NUM_OF_USERS);` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data are allocated on stack. Stacks have limited size and cannot be resized. Allocate such large blocks on heap with `std::vector` or `new[]`.

Comment: Thank you! I allocated it on the heap and worked fine! 
changed it to user* users = new user[NUM_OF_USERS];